# How to create own window rather then use default window

Tags: javafx

I've been working on javafx and i want to remove default windows and create a window with my style

[image]

Comment: Well you could use the `initStyle` method of the `Stage` class: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html) the refeence. Then  you could work with the `css`.

Comment: well then how should i create my own window

Comment: Your window is represented by a Stage passed as a parameter in the `start` method. You have to call `initStyle` on the stage.

Comment: public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

    }

Comment: @ehsanabbas You need to call `initStyle` ***before*** showing the `Stage`...

Comment: @fabian Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to create a window in javafx. To create your own window you need to modify the style of your stage which can be done using initStyle() method.

```
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(createParent(), Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
//        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
//        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        primaryStage.setTitle("My Own Window");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private Parent createParent() {
        Pane rootPane = new Pane();
        rootPane.setPrefSize(1000,400);
        Button btn = new Button("RandomButton");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> Platform.exit());
        rootPane.getChildren().add(btn);
        return rootPane;
    }
}
```